# Insert value from multiple input select (HTML/PHP) into mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an mysql query that returns Name, Surname and Choice.
For every line returned, i have an input select (agree/disagree/maybe/none)

i want to insert the values of all the input select (one for every line returned) into my database in the "advice" field

mysql table: name,surname,choice,advice

i've managed to get the values, but when i try to insert them into the advice field, if i have 3 lines returned, (one advice for every line), all the three advices are stored for every line, and it should be only one.

This is the part where i have the result of the sql query, with an input select for every line returned:

```html
 while( $result = mysql_fetch_object( $requete ) )
  {
  ?>

 

   <table border="1" align="center">
   <tr valign="middle" align="center">
    
    <td width="400"><?php echo "$result->NomEtud"?> </td>  
    <td width="400"><?php echo "$result->PrenomEtud"?> </td> 
    <td width="400"><?php echo "$result->filieres"?> </td>
    
    <td width="100">
    <form method="post" action="validationavis2.php">
    <select name="Avis[]" id="state_id" >
    <option name="Avis[]" value="Très Favorable">Très Favorable</option>
    <option name="Avis[]" value="Favorable">Favorable</option>
    <option name="Avis[]" value="Défavorable">Défavorable</option>
    <option name="Avis[]" value="Sans Opinion">Sans Opinion</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="NomEtud" value="<?php echo($NomEtud) ;?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="PrenomEtud" value="<?php echo($PrenomEtud) ;?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo($id) ;?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="filieres" value="<?php echo($filieres) ;?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="idvoeux[]" value="<?php echo($idvoeux) ;?>"/>      
    


  </table>

 
  <?php
  }//fin if 
  
  
  ?>
  <br><br><br>
<center><input type="submit" name="submit"></button></center>
</form>
```

Now the page where i have the sql query to insert the values of the input select:

```html
<?php
  //connection au serveur
  $cnx = mysql_connect( "localhost", "root", "" ) ;
 
  //sélection de la base de données:
  $db  = mysql_select_db( "choices" ) ;
 
  //récupération des valeurs des champs:
 

 

 
  //nom de la matiere:
 $Avis = $_POST['Avis'] ;
  $NomEtud  = $_POST['NomEtud'] ;
 $PrenomEtud  = $_POST['PrenomEtud'] ;
  $id  = $_POST['id'] ;
  $filieres  = $_POST['filieres'] ;
    $idvoeux  = $_POST['idvoeux'] ;


  

$var = "";
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($Avis);$i++) {
    $var .= "".$Avis[$i]."";
    echo $Avis[$i];


$sql="UPDATE  voeux inner join choixfilieres on voeux.filieres=choixfilieres.filieresprof
SET AVIS='".$var."'
WHERE id='" . $id. "' 
 
";


  //exécution de la requête SQL:
  $requete = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() ) ;
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not give every option a name.
select name='avis'
You just give each option a value

```
<select name="avis">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```